# Would this question be on-topic on PSE?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984832/what-is-the-output-of-grails-stats-for-your-largest-grails-project#question

Never seen this kind of question before.  If I had to bet, it'd get closed asap.

What says the community?

Comment: Apparently not much...

Comment: I would caution against comments that could be interpreted as an "attack" on the community. You have to keep in mind that the meta sites get far less traffic and PSE is a smaller community than SO. Expecting an answer within 40mins is not reasonable.

Comment: @Pem lol I'm trying to protect PSE, not defame it.

Comment: I understand that...I just wanted to point out that the way you delivered that comment may or may not be interpreted the way you indented it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pemdas got it. I'm not seeing a constructive point to that question. It seems like it falls firmly in the "getting to know you" category, which is off-topic on P.SE.

I'm usually in the mod chat room even if I don't have it explicitly opened in a browser, so feel free to @-address me in there if there are questions like this that you want answered quickly. I may not *always* respond right away, but the notification popping up in my SE inbox is better than relying on me checking P.SE meta at the right time. (The same probably goes for the other mods, too, but I can't speak for them.)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to remember that.  I'm trying to reduce the number of posts I migrate from StackOverflow that end up getting closed at PSE.

Comment: @Will Thanks. I appreciate that. :)

Comment: @Will - Many thanks for your efforts.  It is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

It would probably get closed because it is basically a survey and not constructive. You could argue that the result might be used in some constructive fashion, but answers themselves are too localized and not very useful.